# Calculator using JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, textarea, calculator

I am facing little problem..

I am trying to develop a basic GUI calculator using Java. I have used `JTextArea` for entering numbers and performing all calculations in that only. I want the text area to show the final result also but the **basic problem is when I press the plus button. It shows error and it's not showing any result. I know the problem is with `textarea.settext("")` but I don't know how to overcome it**.

I am specifying the vital parts of the code below not the whole code.

This is my code so far:

```
JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
    ta.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 20));
    ta.setBounds(10, 11, 319, 74);
    contentPane.add(ta);


JButton button_14 = new JButton("1 ");
    button_14.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ta.append("1");
        }   


JButton button_17 = new JButton("+");
    button_17.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            num1=Float.parseFloat(ta.getText());
            ta.setText("");
            ta.setText(ta.getText());

            num2=Float.parseFloat(ta.getText());
            ans=num1+num2;

        }

JButton button_11 = new JButton("=");
    button_11.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            ta.setText(String.valueOf(ans));
        }
```

Comment: this does not make sense `ta.setText("");
            ta.setText(ta.getText());`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: *"Plzz I urgently need some help.."* What you need is better time-management skills. Don't come here to tell us your arbitrary (to us) time constraints. We typically prefer helping people who can manage their time better. *"I am specifying the vital parts of the code"* Post a MCVE as mentioned by @xenteros. ***"It shows error"*** Always copy/paste error and exception output!

Comment: Yup, i apologize for such statements...and later i fixed my code to the working state. Thank you @xenteros

Answer (score 0):

You are right about where the problem lies:

```
ta.setText("");
ta.setText(ta.getText());  
num2=Float.parseFloat(ta.getText());
```

What you are doing is setting the text to nothing, then setting the text to nothing again (cos the text is now nothing ).

And the you tried to make a number from nothing.

Nothing meaning: ""

Save the text in a variable before setting it to nothing if that is what you are trying to accomplish or don't set it to "".

Comment: Thanx for the help dude

Comment: @VarunTHK7 Pleasure, if it is the answer you sought could you please approve it.